# PyQt5 QThread crashes when fetching some data

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I try to execute that code, but the program crahes without error message.
if you launch my program and clicked 'collect!' pushButton, sometimes it succeed but it crashes about 70% of time I think
I think It must be problem with CollectThread class
But I don't know why
why this happens? Some good guys plz answer me

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import datetime
import time


class CollectThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.main = parent

    def run(self):
        contents = []
        for i in range(20):
            r = requests.get('http://scoregame.co.kr/game/racing_ajax/moredata/basic/{}'.format(i+1), timeout=None)
            print('fetching {}st data..'.format(i+1))
            for j in r.json():
                contents.append(j)
        print('completed!')

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.th = CollectThread(self)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('collect!', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

   def btn_clicked(self):
       self.th.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I see that it is caused by the exception of the timeout, run it in a cmd and you will see the complete error message.

Comment: *urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb1400a6eb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known*

Comment: *urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='scoregame.co.kr', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /game/racing_ajax/moredata/basic/15 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb1400a6eb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))*